# Unit testing for UI validation

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, selenium, karma-jasmine

Imagine a very simple **Angular** form with two input fields bound to two scope variables and a submit button which calls a controller function as to send the input data in the database.

My question is ***if unit testing may be applied to this scheme***. Is it possible for example to test the UI - input validation?

My guess is no, since I think it must be applied **end to end testing** (e.g. Selenium).

I am struggling as to find an appropriate test: for example *how may I test not allow some characters inside an input field?*

> Am I right to think that unit testing is only for testing the controller methods and the services' ones?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing something manual (out of default validation rules like input[number] then you should check your validation works).

If you are using default validation, you can still check your value of input is correct after the user enters some invalid data.

Examples:

```
 describe('check default validation', function() {
   var $scope, form;
   beforeEach(module('exampleDirective'));
   beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
     $scope = $rootScope;
     var element = angular.element(
       '<form name="form">' +
       '<input ng-model="model.somenum" name="somenum" integer />' +
       '</form>'
     );
     $scope.model = { somenum: null }
     $compile(element)($scope);
     form = $scope.form;
   }));

   describe('input type number should not accept string values', function() {
     it('should pass with integer', function() {
       form.somenum.$setViewValue('3');
       $scope.$digest();
       expect($scope.model.somenum).toEqual('3');
       expect(form.somenum.$valid).toBe(true);
     });
     it('should not pass with string', function() {
       form.somenum.$setViewValue('a');
       $scope.$digest();
       expect($scope.model.somenum).toBeUndefined();
       expect(form.somenum.$valid).toBe(false);
     });
   });
 });
```

Example for custom validation:

```
 var scope, form;

 beforeEach(function() {
   module('my-module');
   module('templates');
 });

 beforeEach(inject($rootScope, $controller, $templateCache, $compile) {
     scope = $rootScope.$new()

     ctrl = $controller('MyController'), {
         "$scope": scope
     }

     templateHtml = $templateCache.get('path/to/my/template.html')
     formElem = angular.element("<div>" + templateHtml + "</div>")
     $compile(formElem)(scope)
     form = scope.form

     scope.$apply()
 }

 it('should not allow an invalid `width`', function() {
   expect(form.$valid).toBeTruthy();
   form.number.$setViewValue('BANANA');
   expect(form.number.$valid).toBeFalsy()
 });
```